# driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint redis : Bind for 0.0.0.0:6379 failed: port is already allocated

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run

```
/usr/bin/docker run --rm -v /var/data/redis:/data -v /var/data/conf/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf --name redis -p 6379:6379 redis:5.0.3-alpine3.9
```

but I get:

```
/usr/bin/docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint redis (f16f19b7727a710fb6c96be566dac66ce26282982960d97faa28861c24fcf2fb): Bind for 0.0.0.0:6379 failed: port is already allocated.
```

When I try to check the ports used with `netstat`, I get:

```
[root@artik ~]# netstat -nlpute | grep 6379
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          14384       2471/docker-proxy
```

I have no docker containers running right now.

I don't understand this issue, what should I do ?

```
[root@artik ~]# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Comment: if the container is still running, may be try to stop and run again?

Comment: nop, no container is running

Comment: Add output of  `docker ps -a`

Comment: nothing neither in docker ps -a

Comment: added to question

Comment: I have rebooted, and now, everything is working. I will never know what happened :(

Comment: reboot always helps :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `netstat` output its clear that there is one process holding port `6379`

```
[root@artik ~]# netstat -nlpute | grep 6379
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          14384       2471/docker-proxy
```

`docker-proxy` processes are created when you do port forwarding in `docker run` which is true in your case `-p 6379:6379`.

For more info on docker-proxy check [this](https://windsock.io/the-docker-proxy/) out.

I suspect that you earlier ran a redis container which used port `6379`, but that container was not properly deleted which kept process `docker-proxy` running and hence you got `port is already allocated`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Steps I had to take to get everything working:

```sh
sudo service docker stop
sudo rm /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db
sudo service docker start
docker system prune
```

And then try again.

Comment: `sudo service docker stop` followed by `sudo service docker start` fixed this for me (without the other commands). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As DannyMoshe suggested for anyone else.

Try this before you potentially mess up your whole setup::

```
sudo service docker stop
sudo service docker start
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the `ports - ...`  in the docker-compose file and let it assign by itself. or change the port mapping in the host from `6379:6379` to `6378:6379` that worked for me. Before doing this you may need to clear already started containers. `docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)`